# Acced denied for root but still logged in phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I'm trying to make a basic login form for my website using php and mysql. I didn't get the phpmyadmin connection working on my raspberry pi, so I tried the code first on my pc with xampp. Got it working, moved everything to the raspberry pi and the connection errors went away. But now everytime I log into the root account, or any other account, I get these[image: these] error messages on the bottom of the page. When I fill in the "sign up" page the website says error=none as reaction, but the accounts are not entering in the database.

```
<?php

$serverName = "localhost";
$dBUsername = "root";
$dBPassword = "";
$dBName = "Beta";

$conn = mysqli_connect($serverName, $dBUsername, $dBPassword, $dBName);

if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: ". mysqli_connect_error());
}
```

I tried uninstalling and reinstalling phpmyadmin, didn't work. And I also tested the code on my pc with xampp. That worked without any problems.

Comment: You are using the wrong password

Comment: _moved everything to the raspberry pi_ Moved what EXACTLY

Comment: But it still logs me into the root account? I moved all the php files i used for the website.

Comment: SO can you login on the pi using the mysql command line tool using root with no password?

Comment: No, I cannot login without password. If I use the password that I created I does work. But on the phpmyadmin website I get those errors after login in. They're on the bottom of the page, but don't seem to be doing or affecting anything

Comment: So `$dBPassword = "";` shoudl be set to the password

Comment: **Hoofing great big note** You should not be using (even in development) the root account. Instead create a new MySQL account with a seperate password and privilages to only see this one database to use in this one app

Comment: I want to get it working first, but even after filling in the password, nothing has changed. Still the same errors on the bottom of the phpmyadmin page and no new accounts in the database

Comment: Unintall and Reinstall the MySQL on the PI and this time pay attention if yo uare asked to create a password for the `root` account. If not then the assount will be blank and an empty password should work

Comment: this tool has like hundreds of security issues. Please just quit using it. MySQL workbench is so much better btw!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Manage to fix it:

I uninstalled mysql, php and phpmyadmin from the raspberry pi. Then reinstalled them. The error messages were gone by this point. I made the table again and made sure that I was not putting the root account in the file, but a new user without password. You are not able to log in with that user because there is no password and my config doesn't allow that. But it does manage to enter new values into the table somehow. Anyways, it works now. Thanks :)